# Does the damage from sun exposure outweigh the benefit of getting vitamin D?

Tags: dermatology, vitamin-d, uv-rays, sun-exposure

I have read some articles where they recommend a direct exposure to the sun of about 20 to 30 minutes, others say that 10 to 15 minutes, another that 5 minutes is enough, etc. I suppose it depends on the geographic region, the seasons of the year, and other conditions.

However, I have found articles that state that in less than 1 minute of sun exposure, the skin begins to suffer damage [(Sun Protection and Vitamin D - The Skin Cancer Foundation)](https://www.skincancer.org/blog/sun-protection-and-vitamin-d/). In [this other](https://qz.com/992779/the-idea-that-you-need-to-get-sun-for-vitamin-d-is-a-myth/) it is stated that the idea that you need to sunbathe to get vitamin D is a myth. [This one](https://www.yalemedicine.org/stories/vitamin-d-myths-debunked/) from Yale Medicine makes a similar claim. In general, all of these articles suggest that it is better to take supplements to cover a vitamin D deficiency than to expose yourself to the sun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your curiosity and logical thinking - you're just missing a few pieces of the puzzle.

The sun emits ultraviolet light radiation which is the component of sunlight that is able to damage skin.

Ultraviolet (UV) is a form of electromagnetic radiation with wavelengths between 10 to 400 nanometers, shorter than that of visible light but longer than X-rays. To put nanometers into perspective - A human hair is around 75,000 nanometers in diameter. There are sub-types of UV which define the wavelength size:

1. Ultraviolet A - UVA - 400–315 nanometers
2. Ultraviolet B - UVB - 315–280 nanometers
3. Ultraviolet C - UVC - 280–100 nanometers

Interestingly UVB is essential synthesize Vitamin D.

UV light is able to damage DNA. This results with humans cells (typically skin cells) to attempt to repair themselves. As a result sometimes genetic mutations arise - some of which give the cell the ability to divide more frequently (cancer). The process of UV damage is shown in the image below.

[image: UV damaging DNA]

Although advertises I'm sure would love you to believe that Vitamin D should always be gained from their supplement, the world health organisation states the following "[...5 to 15 minutes of casual sun exposure of hands, face and arms two to three times a week during the summer months is sufficient to keep your vitamin D levels high.](https://www.who.int/uv/resources/FAQ/uvhealtfac/en/index1.html)". Yes I understand - *supplements avoid aforementioned damage to DNA* - but you will be safe if you follow the above directive (it's free) and learn more information on other methods to prevent damage when in situations of long-term exposure.

In terms of further scientific reading I would like to direct you toward higher quality literature. [This web-page explains the difference between and the best information resource out of: News articles, Journal articles and, Peer-reviewed scientific articles.](https://www.angelo.edu/services/library/handouts/peerrev.php) In saying this, I also think Wikipedia in the 21st century has gained a highly respected and excellent reputation for free high quality information.

[Attached is a Chloropleth map displaying the total average daily ambient ultraviolet radiation (UVR) level across the world.](https://www.who.int/gho/phe/ultraviolet_radiation/exposure/en/)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, the pieces of the puzzle that I was missing. Thank you

Comment: No worries, I'm glad that is helpful.

Comment: WHO links about *"...5 to 15 minutes" & "Attached is a Chloropleth"* are broken.